# ASP.NET MVC 5 connect to multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I want to add multiple databases. All databases have identity tables and I want two work with databases in same controllers.

Search in YouTube but not found it

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: What you talk about is called a **multitenant** app. A lot of docs is available. Broad topic so you'd have to narrow your question to something specific